# Dynamically build JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I need to dynamically build a JSON structure in Python, which I'll pass to an API.   The structure looks like this:

```
{
  "list_name" : "listname0001,listname0002,listname0003",
  "subscriptions" :
  [
    {
      "first_name" : "Subscriber's First Name",
      "last_name" : "Subscriber's Last Name",
      "email" : "subscriber_email0001@api.trumpia.com",
      "mobile" :
      {
        "number" : "2003004000",
        "country_code" : "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Having issues trying to do this properly.  I am sure Python has a JSON object, just not sure how to dynamically build this with the variables and array, etc.

Any help would be great!

Comment: "Dynamically build" from what? Do you have the json as a file?

Comment: Seems that "Dynamically" means by a python script

Comment: You build the matching Python data structure and use `json.dumps()`.

Comment: Yes, trying to write this in Python.   And the data is dynamic, hence looping and reading from an array and placing those values in the JSON structure.

Comment: It really is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Do you mean via input()?

Comment: Basically json is isomorphic to a nested dictionary in Python. If you can create one of those, then you can use the [stdlib json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to create the actual json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper function to dynamically populate the values in a `dict` object with the necessary structure:

```py
from __future__ import annotations


def build_api_request(names: list[str],
                      first: str, last: str,
                      email: str,
                      mobile_no: str,
                      country_code: str | int):
    return {
        "list_name": ','.join(names),
        "subscriptions": [
                {"first_name": first,
                 "last_name": last,
                 "email": email,
                 "mobile": {"number": mobile_no,
                            "country_code": str(country_code)}}
        ]
    }


req = build_api_request(["listname0001", "listname0002", "listname0003"],
                        "Subscriber's First Name",
                        "Subscriber's Last Name",
                        "subscriber_email0001@api.trumpia.com",
                        "2003004000",
                        1)

import json
print(json.dumps(req, indent=2))
```

Prints:

```
{
  "list_name": "listname0001,listname0002,listname0003",
  "subscriptions": [
    {
      "first_name": "Subscriber's First Name",
      "last_name": "Subscriber's Last Name",
      "email": "subscriber_email0001@api.trumpia.com",
      "mobile": {
        "number": "2003004000",
        "country_code": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This appears to work.   Many thanks!!

Comment: @LandonStatis No problem, glad it helped. Feel free to also [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) an answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON {} is either a class or a dictionary and [] is an array.
Simplest thing to do is create a dictionary, add the first level fields and if any of the values is an array, add a list value, if any of the values is an object/dictionary add a dict value.

When you have the compatible structure, serialize it to json.
Try searching for "python serialize to json" for an example or if you have tried something and it failed, post your code for help.

Comment: A class? No. And do you mean a list?

Comment: I wrote what I meant. JSON types (JSON = JavaScript Object Notation) have different names. In Python, as I later wrote - if you read on, you can use dict and list (or create a class a serialize it).

Comment: A JSON object is pretty much never serialized from a class object. And you said "array" not list.

Comment: Perhaps you mean *instances of a class* ... But that isn't very helpful... *everything* is an instance of a class

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga no point in having a discussion here. You define a simple class (e.g. POJO in Java) with the fields you want, instantiate it (therefore create an object) and provide it with the values (e.g. via constructor). This is good if you have a fixed structure. If you have any follow up questions, please ask a question and don't comment here. I recommend you try a few additional languages and not only Python to expand your toolset.

Comment: what are you talking about? The question is asking about Python, in any case, what you are discussing above applies to Python as well. I'm not *asking questions*, I am pointing out that you are using terminology sloppily or incorrectly (as it applies to Python, which is what this question is tagged with)

Comment: I'm explaining what Python types map to what **JSON** types. JSON is not a Python standard.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have a dictionary, you can print the JSON by calling:**

```
import json
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4)) # indent=4 for better formatting
```

Otherwise you would have to build yourself a mix of dictionaries and arrays by just entering something like:

```
data = {
  "list_name" : "listname0001,listname0002,listname0003",
  "subscriptions" :
  [
    {
      "first_name" : "Subscriber's First Name",
      "last_name" : "Subscriber's Last Name",
      "email" : "subscriber_email0001@api.trumpia.com",
      "mobile" :
      {
        "number" : "2003004000",
        "country_code" : "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

you can also just use variables:

```
data = {
  "list_name" : ",".join(list_name),
  "subscriptions" :
  [
    {
      "first_name" : first_name,
      "last_name" : last_name,
      "email" : email,
      "mobile" :
      {
        "number" : mobile_number,
        "country_code" : mobile_country_code
      }
    }
  ]
}
```